# ConstraintLayout android, como manejar vistas GONE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, constraint-layout

estoy armando una pantalla con constraint layout.
La idea final es que la pantalla quede con botones de la siguiente manera:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

El problema que tengo es que no logro acomodar las cosas como requiero, por ejemplo, si cambio la vista de 2 a GONE, el 3 tendria que ocupar su lugar y pasaria a quedar:

```
1 3
4 5
6 7
8
```

Lo maximo que llegue a hacer es, que se remplacen vertical (el 2 es remplazado por el 4) u horizontalmente (el 2 desaparece y solo queda el 1).
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Buenas, Me parece que lograrás tu objetivo de otra manera( puede que con constraint layout se complique mucho las cosas para este caso). Podrías utilizar un Gridlayout y pasarle un arreglo de botones, estos se ordenaran conforme el arreglo que le pases.

Comment: Agrega el layout que estas tratando , recuerda revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar `GONE`, usa `INVISIBLE`

Esto lo que va a hacer es que la vista permanezca pero invisible, en cambio `GONE` va a hacer que tu vista desaparezca de la pantalla y la próxima vista ocupe su lugar